# "Spread" na.locf data for irregular time data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, zoo

I have data like the following:

```
data <- tibble(time = c(ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:33:00"),
                        ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:35:00"),
                        ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:40:00"),
                        ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:52:00")),
               data = c(1250, 900, 4000, 9000))
data
##  A tibble: 4 x 2
#   time                 data
#   <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 2019-11-01 09:33:00  1250
# 2 2019-11-01 09:35:00   900
# 3 2019-11-01 09:40:00  4000
# 4 2019-11-01 09:52:00  9000
```

I want the `data` column to be resampled for every minute between the first and last observation, and I want the value of `data` to become the next non NAN value divided by 1 + the number of nan values from the prior non-nan value to the next non-nan value (i.e. the value of `data` is "spread" back minutely from its given sample point to the prior given sample point).

In this case for instance, I would expect the following

```
> result
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   time                 data
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2019-11-01 09:33:00  1250
 2 2019-11-01 09:34:00   450
 3 2019-11-01 09:35:00   450
 4 2019-11-01 09:36:00   800
 5 2019-11-01 09:37:00   800
 6 2019-11-01 09:38:00   800
 7 2019-11-01 09:39:00   800
 8 2019-11-01 09:40:00   800
 9 2019-11-01 09:41:00   750
10 2019-11-01 09:42:00   750
11 2019-11-01 09:43:00   750
12 2019-11-01 09:44:00   750
13 2019-11-01 09:45:00   750
14 2019-11-01 09:46:00   750
15 2019-11-01 09:47:00   750
16 2019-11-01 09:48:00   750
17 2019-11-01 09:49:00   750
18 2019-11-01 09:50:00   750
19 2019-11-01 09:51:00   750
20 2019-11-01 09:52:00   750
```

How can I do this?

---

I see in Zoo how to use [`na.locf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-6/topics/na.locf) to do *nearly* what I want, but I don't see how to incorporate this "spreading" of the data instead of just filling with last value or doing linear interpolation.

I've also tried using `xts` and merging two series (one of which is the irregular dates) with some custom logic but this is proving challenging for me.

Comment: So why does the `data` entry for `"09:35:00"` change from `900` to `450`? I thought you only want to replace the `NA` entries. And why does the entry for `"09:34:00"` (which would originally be an `NA`) become `450`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers one time step was missing. so 900 would be divided between 2. Same logic happened to 4000 which is divided by 5 (4 timesteps were NA). See my answer.

Comment: @M-- I see. Thanks for the clarification. That seems like an usual way to "interpolate" values. I've posted an answer with a linear interpolation approach.

Comment: @EricHansen I see. Upon re-reading your post more carefully I realise you did say that you wanted to replace entries following a method *different* from linear interpolation. Should've read more carefully;-)

Comment: No sorry it's my bad :) seemed obvious when I wrote it but rereading now it is kind of a strange. domain-specific use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) zoo** Convert to zoo object `z`, insert the NAs using `merge` and then define the groups `g` as consecutive positions which are NA except for the last in the group.  Then compute the required ratios and convert to data frame using `fortify.zoo`.  The last line could be omitted if a zoo series result is ok.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(data)
m <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), 60)))
g <- head(c(0, cumsum(!is.na(m))), -1)
data2 <- na.locf0(m, fromLast = TRUE) /  ave(m, g, FUN = length)
fortify.zoo(data2)
```

giving:

```
                 Index data2
1  2019-11-01 09:33:00  1250
2  2019-11-01 09:34:00   450
3  2019-11-01 09:35:00   450
4  2019-11-01 09:36:00   800
5  2019-11-01 09:37:00   800
6  2019-11-01 09:38:00   800
7  2019-11-01 09:39:00   800
8  2019-11-01 09:40:00   800
9  2019-11-01 09:41:00   750
10 2019-11-01 09:42:00   750
11 2019-11-01 09:43:00   750
12 2019-11-01 09:44:00   750
13 2019-11-01 09:45:00   750
14 2019-11-01 09:46:00   750
15 2019-11-01 09:47:00   750
16 2019-11-01 09:48:00   750
17 2019-11-01 09:49:00   750
18 2019-11-01 09:50:00   750
19 2019-11-01 09:51:00   750
20 2019-11-01 09:52:00   750
```

**2) base** Here is a base solution that is even shorter.  We define a function `ratiofun` which generates the data for one group given its length in minutes and the value of its right endpoint.  Then expand time and apply the function.

```
ratiofun <- function(minutes, data) rep(data/minutes, minutes)
with(data, data.frame(time = seq(min(time), max(time), 60),
  data = unlist(mapply(ratiofun, c(1, diff(time)), data))))
```

giving:

```
                  time data
1  2019-11-01 09:33:00 1250
2  2019-11-01 09:34:00  450
3  2019-11-01 09:35:00  450
4  2019-11-01 09:36:00  800
5  2019-11-01 09:37:00  800
6  2019-11-01 09:38:00  800
7  2019-11-01 09:39:00  800
8  2019-11-01 09:40:00  800
9  2019-11-01 09:41:00  750
10 2019-11-01 09:42:00  750
11 2019-11-01 09:43:00  750
12 2019-11-01 09:44:00  750
13 2019-11-01 09:45:00  750
14 2019-11-01 09:46:00  750
15 2019-11-01 09:47:00  750
16 2019-11-01 09:48:00  750
17 2019-11-01 09:49:00  750
18 2019-11-01 09:50:00  750
19 2019-11-01 09:51:00  750
20 2019-11-01 09:52:00  750
```

Comment: This is really great work, thank you! I'm trying to understand your second answer (not an R expert by any means), and I don't quite get it. For instance, suppose I wanted to do this same filling logic carrying forwards (like locf with `fromLast`) instead of backwards. What changes?

Comment: Ahh it's just changing the position of the 1 in the diffs... this answer is very cool :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr` and `join` the dataframe with the one that has all the timesteps.

Then we can use `tidyr` to `fill` upwards and finally divide by the number of records in each group (i.e. number of timesteps that were missing + 1)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
```

```
data <- tibble(time = c(ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:33:00"),
                        ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:35:00"),
                        ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:40:00"),
                        ymd_hms("2019-11-01 09:52:00")),
               data = c(1250, 900, 4000, 9000))
```

```r
tibble(time = seq.POSIXt(from = min(data$time),
                         to = max(data$time), by="min")) %>%
  left_join(., data, by="time") %>% 
  group_by(id = cumsum(is.na(data) & !is.na(lag(data)))) %>% 
  fill(data, .direction = "up") %>% 
  mutate(data = data/ n())
```

```
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>    time                 data    id
#>    <dttm>              <dbl> <int>
#>  1 2019-11-01 09:33:00  1250     0
#>  2 2019-11-01 09:34:00   450     1
#>  3 2019-11-01 09:35:00   450     1
#>  4 2019-11-01 09:36:00   800     2
#>  5 2019-11-01 09:37:00   800     2
#>  6 2019-11-01 09:38:00   800     2
#>  7 2019-11-01 09:39:00   800     2
#>  8 2019-11-01 09:40:00   800     2
#>  9 2019-11-01 09:41:00   750     3
#> 10 2019-11-01 09:42:00   750     3
#> 11 2019-11-01 09:43:00   750     3
#> 12 2019-11-01 09:44:00   750     3
#> 13 2019-11-01 09:45:00   750     3
#> 14 2019-11-01 09:46:00   750     3
#> 15 2019-11-01 09:47:00   750     3
#> 16 2019-11-01 09:48:00   750     3
#> 17 2019-11-01 09:49:00   750     3
#> 18 2019-11-01 09:50:00   750     3
#> 19 2019-11-01 09:51:00   750     3
#> 20 2019-11-01 09:52:00   750     3
```